# transition when using $("class").load ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have main html showing 8 thumbnails from section A, when clicking on section B i will use `$("content").load` to load section B thumbnails.

Working fine but i wonder how i can make transition happen instead of the dull changing way..

Thanks

```
<div class="loadContent">
    <div class="sixteen full columns alpha omega">
        <div class="img_section four full columns alpha omega">
            <img class="four full columns test_img alpha omega" src="http://i.imgur.com/MwegAOI.jpg" alt="logo">
             <h2 class="caption">sectionA<br />Featured Portfolio1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="img_section four full columns alpha omega">
            <img class="four full columns test_img alpha omega" src="http://i.imgur.com/MwegAOI.jpg" alt="logo">
             <h2 class="caption">sectionA<br />Featured Portfolio2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="img_section four full columns alpha omega">
            <img class="four full columns test_img alpha omega" src="http://i.imgur.com/MwegAOI.jpg" alt="logo">
             <h2 class="caption">sectionA<br />Featured Portfolio3</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="img_section four full columns alpha omega">
            <img class="four full columns test_img alpha omega" src="http://i.imgur.com/MwegAOI.jpg" alt="logo">
             <h2 class="caption">sectionA<br />Featured Portfolio4</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use jquery effects (slide,fadeIn or show) while selecting the section A div.

Comment: can u show me an example?

Comment: Have a loot at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/238qcqh1/)